# Prevent CSS3 animation from firing after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

My problem is that my animation is firing immediately after the page loads.

Consider the following CSS:

```
.panel {
    opacity: 0;
}
.loaded .panel {
    -webkit-animation: hidepanel 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.panel.active {
    -webkit-animation: showpanel 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes showpanel {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes hidepanel {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

... and the following JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('body').addClass('loaded');
});
```

In this configuration, the *hidepanel* animation fires immediately after the page is loaded. However, what I'd to happen is the *hidepanel* animation to **only** fire after I have added and then removed the *active* class.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to manually assign the *loaded* class each time I want to see the *hidepanel* animation?

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the problem. You can see the red box initially fades out. This represents what happens to my element when the page loads.
http://jsfiddle.net/Tz9p4/

**Update**
I ended up going with this as a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Tz9p4/1/. I still think wish there was a better way other than checking for the *loaded* class every time I want to call the *hidepanel* animation, but it seems currently there is not.

Comment: So you want the page to load, the panel to fade in, and then then panel to fade out?

Comment: @apaul34208 Actually, I want no animation to occur whatsoever (immediately) after the page loads. When I add the class _active_ it will run the _showpanel_ animation, then when I remove the class _active_ the _hidepanel_ animation works fine. The only problem is that when the page initially loads, the _hidepanel_ animation runs, which I don't want.

Comment: How would you like to add and remove the class if not on load? are you pushing a button? waiting X seconds? or what?

Comment: @apaul34208 I have other code that adds or removes the _active_ class at the appropriate time (login button). I suppose I could just **not** apply the _loaded_ class on window.load, but rather when I remove the _active_ class I could add the _loaded_ class if it's not already there. But that seems like extra code.

Comment: Have you considered using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` like: http://jsfiddle.net/7E6Sj/

Comment: @apaul34208 I have, but they tax the CPU a lot more than a CSS animation, ergo I'd like to avoid using jQuery to handle animations.

Comment: I'd have to see your specific use case, can you add your html and the other code that adds and removes the active class to your question?

Comment: @apaul34208 I have added a link to a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify what you have a bit.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tz9p4/3/)**

```js
$('#btnLogin').click(function() {
  $('.panel').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.panel {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 2s;
}
.panel.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body">
  <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
<button id="btnLogin">Login</button>
```

Comment: Excellent. I never thought of using transitions. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove that addClass line from the $(window).load().  It won't animate, and you can add the class when you're ready to animate.  Also I usually suggest $(document).ready() as an alternative to $(window).load() as ready fires after the document has loaded and load fires more immediately, possibly before the whole page has rendered.  That's just a minor detail, though.

Comment: I agree that would work, but it seems like extra code to have to check for the _loaded_ class every time I want to fade the element out. Is there no way to do it with just CSS?

Comment: CSS has no events, so it does whatever it's supposed to immediately.  Your JS can control the CSS, meaning when you add the class the CSS gets triggered.  What I would suggest is have the loaded/unloaded class run the animations, and don't add either class on page load.  This will not trigger an animation, and your control can happen at the appropriate times.

Comment: It seems as though this will have to do... I didn't know that modifying a parent's class list would trigger events of the children nodes.